# Solaris - Get directory names that starts with a pattern

Tags: awk, grep, regular-expression

I'm  working on Sun Solaris 10 OS, which is `grep -o` is not allowed with modern systems. I have the below list of directory I'm  trying to fetch any directory starts with `DATA[0-9]` only

```
DATA34016
DATA34011
DATA34029
DATA34027
DATA34014
DATA34013
DATA34010
DATA34006
DATA34008
DATA34007
DATA34026
DATA34009
DATA34015
DATA34017
DATA34012
DATA34028
DATA34067
DATA34066
DATA34046
DATA34046dsd
DATA34046ttidid
```

expected result :

```
DATA34016
DATA34011
DATA34029
DATA34027
DATA34014
DATA34013
DATA34010
DATA34006
DATA34008
DATA34007
DATA34026
DATA34009
DATA34015
DATA34017
DATA34012
DATA34028
DATA34067
DATA34066
DATA34046
```

the main problem my command also takes `DATA34046dsd` and `DATA34046ttidid`

command :

```
for i in $(ls -d */ | grep ^'DATA[0-9]'); do echo ${i%%/}; done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `awk` with a range operator. If you are using a really older version of `awk`, the range interval flag can be specified explcitly

```
awk '/^DATA[0-9]{5}$/' file
awk --re-interval '/^DATA[0-9]{5}$/' file
```

But that said, you should never parse output of `ls`. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use shell built-in glob features. You could just do below to run the loop over the directory names

```
for dir in DATA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]; do
    [ -d "$dir" ] || continue
    printf '%s\n' "$dir"
done
```

Comment: its list of directory not file, like you are trying to do ls -lrt DATA*

Comment: @mashro3ak: did you run the for loop and got the output you needed?

Comment: +1. btw, you can skip the `[ -d "$dir" ]` test if you add a `/` to the end of the glob pattern - it will only match directories.  e.g. `for dir in DATA[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ ; do printf '%s\n' "$dir" ;done`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```
setopt extended_glob

for dir in DATA[[:digit:]](#c5)(/); do
    print $dir
done
```

or just

```
printf '%s\n' DATA[[:digit:]](#c5)(/)
```

The extended globbing pattern `DATA[[:digit:]](#c5)(/)` would match any name that starts with the string `DATA`, followed by exactly five digits (`[[:digit:]](#c5)`), and which refers to a directory (`(/)`).